# Getting the location of cell when clicked in DataGridView C# windows form

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview, click

I have a `DataGrid` in a Windows Form application and I wanted to get the location of the cell the user clicks in and also display the content of the row.

I have 4 columns and the number of rows vary.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Cheers

Comment: Sorry, its for Windows Form application. No server or anything like that

Comment: My apologies, I made a poor assumption that this was asp .net (I'm seeing tags that aren't there!). Sorry.

Comment: No worries I am trying the solution you posted as we speak =D

Comment: In case you struggle, I've edited my answer to include some demo code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx

You will want to leverage the CellClick event to handle this.

Hook the event handler method (one similar to that in the article above) to your datagrid and you have all the information you need in the args passed to the method (`e.RowIndex` for example).

**Creating the Event Handler**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  //Do what you want here with e.RowIndex or e.ColumnIndex, for example
}
```

**Hooking It Up**

```
this.dataGridView1.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellClick);
```

Comment: Hi, What does the second part of your code do? Sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: No problem, we were all beginners at some stage. The first code snippet I've included is a method that will handle an event. i.e. This method will be called when something happens. The second code snippet is code that says "THIS is when to fire the event handler". So we've got the dataGridView1, and we're 'wiring up' the event handler method we created to the CellClick event. The "+=" part of the code is, in effect, saying 'add this event handler to this event'. When somebody now invokes the CellClick event, it now knows to call the event handler.